# error :Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, maven

i have two child projects:project1 and project2 and main project as parent project. 
By adding dependency of project2 in project1,i am using HibernateSession.java class of project2.
It works properly in sts.But when i run jar it gives an error System env is

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/main/hibernateSession

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.main</groupId>
        <artifactId>project2</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you built project1 with maven before you are running project2?

Comment: @ManishKothari yes i did that but still the same error.

Comment: Have you added the jar you created onto your classpath?

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: I guess you might be running your project as 'java -jar someclassname' before invoking this call 'set CLASSPATH=<path_of_yourJar>' (For Windows machines only), The syntax is different for linux machines